# What is the procedure to access physical address using page map table after swap in swap out of the pages

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

A process `P1` having 4 pages.

1. page#1
2. page#2
3. page#3
4. page#4

Their `PMT` is implemented in memory, and their corresponding frame number are `f1, f2, f3, and f4` respectively.

If one of the pages is swapped out and other process's page is swapped in and get frame that earlier belongs to process `P1`. Then `PMT` of process `P1` is modified or what will happen ? because now that frame doesn't not belong to `P1`.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the use-case here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth not getting an F- grade.

Answer (score 0):

If a page table entry for a process no longer maps to a page frame of the process, the operating system must indicate that in the page table. If the operating system takes a physical page frame mapped to P1's logical address space then maps it to P2's logical address space, the operating system must unmap the page frame in P1 (ignoring shared memory).